# How do I create a public playlist through the soundcloud API?

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud, playlist

As a soundcloud user I can create a public playlist and add any track on soundcloud to it.

How do I recreate this behavior through the soundcloud api in javascript?

the [guide stipulates you must own the tracks you want add to a playlist](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#creating-sets), This is clearly not the action I am trying to perform.

Given a group of url's or id's, how do I create a public playlist?

Comment: Same problem here. Nevertheless the ruby version works ok.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with AngularJS, OAuth headers and ngResource. First you need to be authenticated (1 to 4), then you can create the playlist passing the credentials (5 to 7).

1/ Use the Soundcloud Javascript SDK to authenticate your client (see http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#authentication).

2/ Fetch the access token using `SC.accessToken()`

3/ Add the OAuth authorisation header to the `$http` service:

```
 $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "OAuth #{accessToken}"
```

4/ Configure your angular app to pass the credentials in the AJAX requests:

```
ngApp.config([
  '$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    return delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
  }
]);
```

5/ I use a service using `ngResource` (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) to facilitate the API requests:

```
angular.module('ngApp.services').factory('SCPlaylists', [
  '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('https://api.soundcloud.com/me/playlists/:id', null, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

6/ Here's the playlist object:

```
{title: "abc", sharing: "private"}
```

7/ Finally, the playlist creation:

```
$scope.newPlaylist = SCPlaylists.save({}, {
  playlist: playlist
}, function(playlist) {
  return console.log(playlist);
});
```

I hope it helps!